# How to link a pdf file to a specific feature with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pdf, hyperlink, parcel

I'm trying to link a pdf to a parcel (see image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ienKm.jpg) where you click on one parcel and a specific pdf comes up and if you click on another then a different pdf comes up.

I've got it so far that if you click on a parcel it shows a pdf but the problem is that is shows the same pdf for every parcel!

Is there anyway I can assign it to just one parcel by lets say the objectid?

I'm having trouble setting the action so that it opens each parcel.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a text field in the parcel table. This field will contain the path to the PDF file, a different one for each parcel. Then you can set the action on this field to open the PDF file.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, any idea on how to properly set the path on the new field? And how would i set the action to the field? Sorry I'm pretty new to QGIS.

Comment: The cmd / c "[% url %]" worked under actions, thanks guys!