# How to link pdf to a shapefile?

Tags: qgis, pdf, hyperlink

I know that a lot of people asked already that question, I read all of the answers and have also seen all the videos, but I still don’t understand how to link a pdf file to an object.

I have a huge database with the biotopes of a region.  Now I want to add to a few biotopes a pdf file (Similar to [How to link a pdf file to a specific feature with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/154143/115)). For that, I created a new column named “Action” and in that column I wrote the exact path where the pdf file is stored on my computer (but just for biotopes I need with a pdf file). 
Now if I click on one biotope it just opens the attribute list of that shapefile and I can see the path to the pdf file, but it doesn’t open the pdf

In the properties I also wrote down the path, where the pdf files are stored, but it still doesn't work and I don’t really understand what is wrong?

Comment: please share a link to "Emanuel" and also provide some more info about the software you use!

Comment: Sorry of course. That is the link to Emanuel: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154143/how-to-link-a-pdf-file-to-a-specific-feature-with-qgis and I use the QGIS Version 2.12.3-Lyon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you created the action, make sure to use the button "update" action. 
I have a simple example in this video how to add actions:
https://youtu.be/ONVB_lDt2O8

Comment: Wowww thank you so much! I thought I have to write down the whole path in the properties action as well, but I just needed the name of my new created column. Thanks a lot!!